# How to form a new polygon by removing the overlap of polygon A and B from A

Tags: geometry

Assuming I have two polygon's A and B I want to form a new polygon C where C is polygon A less the intersection of polygon A and B.

Is there a common algorithm for this? Or anyone any ideas on where to start with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some algoritm names here: [Boolean operations on polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons).

If you are going to use external library, try [Clipper library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/) (uses Vatti's algo)

Comment: Thanks @MBo I'll have a look at Vatti's algorithm and the Clipper Library.